# set grid layout column to half the width in android

Tags: android, layout, grid-layout

I have a grid layout with two images in two different columns and the images don't fill all of available space.

I need the both columns to be half the width (as for now the left most one is larger than the other). how can I do that?

this is what I have so far but the blackBowl is taking most of the space...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.whitepebbles"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity2" >

<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    app:columnCount="4" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/whiteBowl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_gravity="center|top"
        app:layout_row="5" 
        android:background="@drawable/wbowl00"
        app:layout_columnSpan="2"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/blackBowl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_column="3"
        app:layout_columnSpan="2"
        app:layout_gravity="center"
        app:layout_row="5"
        android:background="@drawable/bbowl00" />

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Comment: using weights might help :\

Comment: I'm not sure weights works in a gridlayout...

Comment: i haven't tested it yet... if you could post the code, may be I could help more precisely.

Comment: I edited the question to include the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figure it out with the support library v7 revision 21.0.2 (I tested with 3 TextViews):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:columnCount="3"
        >
        <TextView
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:text="1"
            />
        <TextView
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:text="2"
            />
        <TextView
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:text="3"
            />
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

The code above produces a single row with three TextViews that uses 1/3 of the available space.